# list more than one field in lists laravel method

Tags: php, laravel

I am using [Zizaco/entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) laravel package and suppose I want to fetch users with `teacher` role.

I want return selected users and their `name` and `family` combination like this :

```
[
    1   =>  'ali nasiri',
    2   =>  'majid basirati'
]
```

For that, I wrote this code :

```
$teachers =
    Role::where('name', 'teacher')->first()->users()->lists('name', 'users.user_id');
```

But that returns like this :

```
{
    "1": "ali",
    "2": "majid"
}
```

Means that only name field was returned because we can define one field in first Parameter of `lists` method.

How Can I do that and what is best solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **user model**, add a custom attribute([accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)):

```
<?php

use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait;

class User extends Eloquent
{
    use EntrustUserTrait; // add this trait to your user model

    ...
    protected $appends = ['full_name'];

    //Setter of full name attribute
    public function getFullNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->name.' '.$this->surname;
    }
}
```

Then use it to access the full name:

```
$teachers = User::whereHas('roles',function($q){
    return $q->where('name','teacher');
})
->get()
->lists('full_name');
```

Comment: this error occured : `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'full_name' in 'field list' (SQL: select `full_name`, `users`.`user_id` from `users` inner join `role_user` on `users`.`user_id` = `role_user`.`user_id` where `role_user`.`role_id` = 4)`

Comment: Modified the answer, to include querying through relationships. Should work now.

Comment: Thanks @Mysteryos your solution returns An array of full_name users. I change `lists()` method to `->lists('full_name','user_id');` for my purpose. Please edit it in answer.